NAT table skipped for server replies running inside Docker container
I have a Docker container running on a vanilla setup which listens on port 9999:
docker run --rm -it -p 9999:9999 busybox nc -vvl -p 9999 0.0.0.0

I added a LOG rule to the POSTROUTING table on NAT in order to capture the server packets. However, when I connect from an external machine to this container, I see nothing in the system log.
I can see connection packets when logging at the tail of mangle's POSTROUTING chain, though. According to The Diagram(TM), NAT-POSTROUTING should be the next chain to travel.
This is the NAT table:
# iptables -nL -tnat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER     0    --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER     0    --  0.0.0.0/0           !127.0.0.0/8          ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        0    --  172.16.0.0/12        0.0.0.0/0            LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "Packet:"
MASQUERADE  0    --  172.17.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0           
MASQUERADE  6    --  172.17.0.2           172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:9999

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     0    --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
DNAT       6    --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:9999 to:172.17.0.2:9999

Watching journalctl -f | grep Packet: shows nothing. TRACE indicates the NAT table is altogether skipped, that is, all chains are skipped for outgoing packets from the server.
This is set:
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=1
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables=1

Why does this happen in this case? Or more generally, why some packets just skip the NAT table completely?

The NAT table is consulted only once for each connection.
When an incoming connection request is received, it has a remote source address and the host address as destination: src=remote and dst=host.
The first PREROUTING rule throws the packet to the DOCKER chain, which eventually DNATs it to the container's address: dst=container. Since this is prerouting, the packet is thus routed to the container.
The third POSTROUTING rule MASQUERADEs the packet source address: src=host (equivalent to SNAT in this case). This makes the container perceive the packet as coming from the host, and thus will reply directly to the host. The host will un-NAT the packets and send back to the remote.
This means the connection is now fully NATted from (remote, host) to (host, container), and the NAT table is not consulted again for this connection.
